prisma generate problem ( The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined )
hello guys i recently workings on a nextjs project ( turborepo - monorepo )
and after few minutes i realized that i have to add new column in my table
so i just updated my schema.prisma by adding a line ( createdAt   DateTime)
then after running npx prisma migrate dev it says you can generate the prisma client
but as we run npx prisma generate it says

PS D:\GitHub\my-turborepo\packages\db> npx prisma generate


Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Error:
The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

The Solution is
Step - 1 :  Open Task manager
Step - 2 :  Kill node.js runtime
Step - 3 :  Kill VsCode ( save changes before killing)
Step - 4 : Open Vs code and before npm run dev run npx prisma generate in your db or main folder of database
And All set :) tell me if it work for you or not
Also if someone know how to fix this in MAC so help others too...

I encountered the Prisma error "The 'path' argument must be of string. Received undefined". A complete reinstallation of packages resolved the issue:
bashCopy# Remove existing packages
npm uninstall @prisma/client prisma
Reinstall packages
npm install prisma --save-dev
npm install @prisma/client
Generate Prisma client
npx prisma generate --schema=./prisma/schema.prisma  # If schema is in custom location
OR
npx prisma generate  # If you're in directory containing prisma/
